# Get selected drop-down value of a row in html table using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html table with 4 columns and multiple rows

```
column1 : simple text
column2 : simple text
column3 : select list with 2 values
column4 : Button that performs some operation
```

At run time, I want to get the selected / entered values for all the columns of that row against which `column4` button is clicked.  I know a little of JavaScript/jQuery.

Here is the static table code

```
<table id="invoiceTbl" border="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Broker info</th>
            <th>Receivable Amount</th>
            <<th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And I am populating table i.e. inserting data on AJAX call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#searchDetails').serialize(),
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "/opsadmin/search.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        var i = 1;
        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
            alert(index + ": " + value.brokerInfo);
            $('table#invoiceTbl TBODY').append('<tr> <td>' + i + '</td><td>' + value.brokerInfo + '</td><td>' + value.receivableAmount + '</td><td><select name="act" id="s"><option>PENDING</option><option>CLEARED</option></select></td><td><input type="button" value="Process" onclick="updateStatus(\'' + index + '\')"</input></td></tr>');
            i++;
        });
    }
});
return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the unique ID to each of your "select" with help of index like:

```
'<select name="act" id="s'+ index +'">'
```

and pass the index with "updateStatus(index)" function call.

```
function updateStatus(index) {
    $('#s'+index).val(); // value of selected box.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `#button` click you will get an array (arr) that holds the values of the clicked row cells:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   var arr = [];
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function() {
      var that = $(this);
      if (that.find('input[type="text"]').length > 0) {
         arr.push(that.find('input[type="text"]').val());
      } else if (that.find('select').length > 0) {
         arr.push(that.find('select').val());
      } else {
         arr.push(that.text());
      }
   });  
  alert(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
          <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
          <option value="opt3">opt3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><button id="button">Click</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am calling one function on button click..should i write your code in that function?

Comment: The function you are calling is getting data from a .json file and append these data to the table. The function in my answer alerts an array that contains the values of each cell in the clicked row. These are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#invoiceTbl input[type=button]").click(function(e){
   $(e.target).closest("tr").find("td").slice(0,2).each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already a few good answers, but my solution is a bit different:

```
$("#invoiceTbl tr").each(function(){
    var select = $(this).find("select");
    var button = $(this).find("button");
    button.click(function(){
        alert(select.val());
    });
});
```

If you also want the content of the other columns, that's a bit more difficult:

```
$("#invoiceTbl tr").each(function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    var button = $(this).find("button");
    button.click(function(){
        tr.find("td").each(function(){
            var select = $(this).find("select");
            var td_button = $(this).find("button");
            if(!td_button.length)
            {
                if(select.length)
                    console.log(select.val());
                else
                    console.log($(this).text());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/cgfjewoe/ to see it run.